# UITableViewCell UILabel Multiple Lines Aligment

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, vertical-alignment

I'm using a standard prototype cell with a label and a detail text. I set the detail text to be two lines and set the text to something with a line break. This works fine - however, the (left aligned) main label has lost its vertical centering, though I didn't change any of its attributes.

This is what it looks like in Storyboard:

[image: Screenshot from Interface Builder]

"Title" should be vertically centered.

Comment: ive never worked with storyboards, could you just redo the rect of the main label to cover the entire cell so it will auto center vertically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom cell in which you can define the attributes of the custom properties.The size of the text label is not fixed. I think this is the reason why the alignment does not work.

Comment: This brought me to the right track. Setting the type to Custom does do the trick. I still had to create a UITableViewCell subclass to connect the labels to the code, but theres probably no way around that. Thanks!

Comment: If you don't want to use a custom UITableViewCell, you can rewrite the method -(void)layoutSubviews; for the UITableViewCell by category.in this method, you can set all the subviews' properties, like textLabel, imageView and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass the UITableViewCell and do your layout in the initWithStyle method.  For ex:

MyCustomCell.h file:

```
@interface MyCustomCell : UITableViewCell
{
    UILabel *_label1;
    UILabel *_label2;
    UILabel *_titleLabel;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *label1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *label2;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *titleLabel;
@end
```

MyCustomCell.m file:

```
#import "MyCustomCell.h"

@implementation MyCustomCell
@synthesize label1 = _label1;
@synthesize label2 = _label2;
@synthesize titleLabel = _titleLabel;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.label1 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, w, h)];  //x: x coordinate, y: y coordinate, w is width , h is height
        self.label2 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, w, h)];
        self.titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, w, h)];
        self.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Times New Roman" size:30.0f]; //change font name and size per your needed.
        [self addSubview:self.label1];
        [self addSubview:self.label1];
        [self addSubview:self.titleLabel];
    }
    return self;
}
```

In the class file where you have `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, make sure include the `#import "MyCustomCell.h"` and  use `MyCustomCell` instead of `UITableViewCell` to allocate the cell.  And assigning data to labels as so:

```
cell.label1.text = xxxx;
cell.label2.text = xxxx;
cell.titleLabel.text = xxxx;
```

Comment: Thanks! I know that's possible, but I'd like to save that additional class.